# Changing background image not working on iOS , only web (ionic app)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ionic-framework

I have a background image in an ionic app that is set by the return of a piece of data from firebase. It works in web but not in the iOS emulator or the iPhone
The background image is styled through in-line html because normal styles weren't working... Why is it working in web but not iOS ? Thank you!

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="change" style="background: url(img/oldPic.png) center; background-size: cover;">
```

js

```
if (changingIntgr <= 3){document.getElementById("change").setAttribute("style", "background: url(img/newPic.png) center; background-size: cover;");}
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the Ios webview component

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but you should try to use the ngClass directive to change the style instead of the ugly inline CSS. Or did you mean this by "normal styles weren't working"?